# Encountering the Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file" when using trunk version of FOP to transform to PDF

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am executing the below code by using the trunk version of FOP.jar,Xml-commons.jar,batik.jar using the following code:

```
package com.test.fop.renderer;



import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent;
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopConfParser;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryBuilder;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 * This class demonstrates the conversion of an XML file to PDF using
 * JAXP (XSLT) and FOP (XSL-FO).
 */
public class ExampleXML2PDF2 {

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args command-line arguments
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws SAXException 
     * @throws ConfigurationException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //xmlToPdf();
        File baseDir = new File("G:\\TestDirectory\\");
        File outDir = new File(baseDir, "Output");
        outDir.mkdirs();
        System.out.println(new Date());
        // Setup input and output files
        File xmlfile = new File("C:\\Users\\diksha\\Desktop\\test.xml");
        File xsltfile = new File("C:\\Users\\diksha\\Desktop\\testxsl.xslt);

     // configure fopFactory as desired


        //DefaultConfigurationBuilder cfgBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
       // Configuration cfg = cfgBuilder.buildFromFile(new File("F:\\userConfig.xconf"));

        //fopFactory.setUserConfig(cfg);
        //fopFactory.setUserConfig(userConfig);
        //getFontManager().setFontBaseURL("file:///C:/Windows/Fonts");
       String confFile = "F:\\userConfig.xconf";
        FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopConfParser(new File(confFile)).getFopFactoryBuilder();
        builder.setStrictFOValidation(false);
        FopFactory fopFactory = builder.build();

        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        foUserAgent.setProducer("NewP");
        foUserAgent.setCreator("NewC");
        foUserAgent.setConserveMemoryPolicy(true);

      //  foUserAgent.setComplexScriptFeaturesEnabled(false);

     // Setup XSLT
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));

        // Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet
        transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");
       // transformer.setParameter("DIRS_BASE", System.getenv("DIRS_BASE"));

        for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        try {
            System.out.println("FOP ExampleXML2PDF\n");
            System.out.println("Preparing...");

            // Setup directories




            String path="F:/Test/Frontsheet/testpdf_summary_border.pdf";
            File pdffile = new File(path);


            System.out.println("Input: XML (" + xmlfile + ")");
            System.out.println("Stylesheet: " + xsltfile);
            System.out.println("Output: PDF (" + pdffile + ")");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Transforming...");


            // configure foUserAgent as desired


            // Setup output

            OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
            out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);

            try {
                // Construct fop with desired output format

                //ByteArrayOutputStream out1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


            //  Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);
              //  fopFactory.setStrictValidation(false);


                //System.out.println(transformer.getParameter("versionParam"));
                // Setup input for XSLT transformation
                //PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();

                Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);

                // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());//StreamResult(out);//fop.getDefaultHandler()

                // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                System.out.println("transforming"+new Date());

                transformer.transform(src, res);
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }

            System.out.println("Success!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        System.out.println(new Date());
        }
    }

}
```

Encountering the Runtime Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file".
Tried using the URI as parameter to create a new file using new File(URI) but could not resolve the error.
The line causing the error and the exception is as below :

```
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:421)
   at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontCache.addFont(FontCache.java:335)
   at org.apache.fop.fonts.DefaultFontConfigurator.getFontInfo(DefaultFontConfigurator.java:167)
   at org.apache.fop.fonts.DefaultFontConfigurator.addFonts(DefaultFontConfigurator.java:136)
   at org.apache.fop.fonts.DefaultFontConfigurator.configure(DefaultFontConfigurator.java:89)
   at org.apache.fop.render.PrintRendererConfigurator.getCustomFontCollection
   (PrintRendererConfigurator.java:147)
   at org.apache.fop.render.PrintRendererConfigurator.setupFontInfo
   (PrintRendererConfigurator.java:127)
   at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFUtil.setupFonts(IFUtil.java:170)
   at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.setupFontInfo(IFRenderer.java:187)
   at org.apache.fop.area.RenderPagesModel.<init>(RenderPagesModel.java:75)
   at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.setupModel(AreaTreeHandler.java:135)
   at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.<init>(AreaTreeHandler.java:105)
   at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.createFOEventHandler(RendererFactory.java:350)
   at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.<init>(FOTreeBuilder.java:107)
   at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.createDefaultHandler(Fop.java:104)
   at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.<init>(Fop.java:78)
   at org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent.newFop(FOUserAgent.java:179)
   at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newFop(FopFactory.java:220)
   at com.diksha.fop.renderer.ExampleXML2PDF2.main(ExampleXML2PDF2.java:143)
```

Comment: Since there is not a single URI seen in your code example, it would be helpful to tell, where in that code this exception occurs.

Comment: Specifically, please include the exception's stack trace in your question.

Comment: Please find the updated question and let me know if you have any solutions.

Comment: Please tell us the content of the URI that you tried ' to create a new file using new File(URI)' with.

Comment: Iam trying to create a PDF file using new File and the path is to the folder in a local harddrive  F:\test

Comment: This exception message relates most likely to one of your "font-embed-url"'s configured in your userConfig.xconf